# Обобщённый метод для чтения данных из файла

Tags: java, generics

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как написать обобщённый метод чтения данных из файла. Например, в одном случае нужно считать строки, в другом - целые числа.
Как написать метод типа такого:

```
    public static <T> List<T> readFromFile(Path pathIn, TypeValue typeValue){...};
```

Корректен ли такой код:

```
public static List readFromFile(Path pathIn, TypeValue typeValue){
        try(Scanner in = new Scanner(pathIn)) {
            if (typeValue == TypeValue.typeInt) {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                    list.add(in.nextInt());
                }
                return list;
            } else {
                List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(pathIn);
                return list;
            }
        } catch (IOException e){ 
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Здесь `pathIn` - путь к файлу с данными, `typeValue` - флаг для обозначения данных (`Integer`, `String` и т.д.).
Смущает, что возвращается не параметризованный `List`. Как вообще решается задача чтения из файла, если формат данных может быть разным - `Integer`, `Double`, `String` и т.д.? Или следует писать для каждого типа данных свой код для чтения? Как-то громоздко тогда получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функционал из Java 8 Stream & Lambda позволяет передавать в метод функциональный интерфейс, который будет применен к потоку данных:

```
public void start() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("test");
    List<String> resultStringList = readFile(path, Function.identity());
    List<Integer> resultIntList = readFile(path, Integer::parseInt);
}

public <T> List<T> readFile(Path path, Function<String, T> func) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path)
            .map(func)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> Или следует писать для каждого типа данных свой код для чтения?

Не самый плохой вариант: написать отдельные методы для каждого типа (в `Scanner`, например, так и сделали) .

> Как-то громоздко тогда получается.

В Вашем варианте вместо нескольких коротких методов используется один, в котором в одном большом `if` будет код всех этих методов.

**Альтернатива**

Можно обернуть метод в интерфейс и применить полиморфизм:

```
//интерфейс
interface ListReader<T> {
    List<T> read(String path);
}

//все общие функции вынесем в отдельный базовый класс
abstract class BaseListReader<T> implements ListReader<T> {
    @Override
    public List<T> read(String path) {
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(path)) {
            List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (hasNext(in)) {
                list.add(next(in));
            }
            return list;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    abstract boolean hasNext(Scanner in) throws IOException;
    abstract T next(Scanner in) throws IOException;
}

class IntListReader extends BaseListReader<Integer> {
    @Override
    boolean hasNext(Scanner in) throws IOException {
        return in.hasNextInt();
    }
    @Override
    Integer next(Scanner in) throws IOException {
        return in.nextInt();
    }
}

class StringListReader extends BaseListReader<String> {
    @Override
    boolean hasNext(Scanner in) throws IOException {
        return in.hasNext();
    }
    @Override
    String next(Scanner in) throws IOException {
        return in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Затем создать фабрику:

```
//Метод для создания
public ListReader createReader(Class clazz) {
    if (clazz == Integer.class) {
        return new IntListReader();
    } else if (clazz == String.class) {
        return new StringListReader();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("clazz");
}
```

В такой реализации обработка разных типов будет отделена друг от друга и от классов-клиентов (публичным может быть только интерфейс `ListReader`). Это позволит протеститровать их отдельно от других классов приложения/использовать класы повторно.

Насколько это оправдано нужно решать по ситуации. Если код будет использован один раз, требования к нему изменяться не будут и нет строгих требований к качеству (покрытие тестами, ограничение сложности методов), то может быть достаточно просто разбить на отдельные методы.

> Смущает, что возвращается не параметризованный List

Эта проблема не решена (возвращается не параметризованный `ListReader`). Решение зависит от того как используется результат метода. Если полученный список обрабатывается как `List<Object>` то метод можно оставить непараметризованным. Если в дальнейшем объекты из списка приводятся к типу, то стоить рассмотреть возможность параметризации фабрик и клиентского кода.