# Типовая безопасность, обобщения и компактный код

Tags: java, generics

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как правильно использовать обобщения, чтобы сохранялась типобезопасность.
Например, в этом коде приходится дублировать функции `sort` и `saveToFile`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Path path = Paths.get("in.txt");
    try {
        if (args[0].equals("i")) {
            List<Integer> list = ...;
            sort(list);
            saveToFile(list, path);
        } else {
            List<String> list = ...;
            sort(list);
            saveToFile(list, path);
        }
    } catch (IOException e){}
}
```

Если эти функции вынести из блока, то `list` не будет типобезопасным (т.е. не будет параметризован):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Path path = Paths.get("in.txt");
    List list;
    try {
        if (args[0].equals("i")) {
           list = ...
        } else {
            list = ...
        }
        sort(list);
        saveToFile(list, path);
    } catch (IOException e){}
}
```

Как избежать дублирования кода и не пожертвовать типобезопасностью?

Comment: А что если вынести эти две функции в ещё одну функцию? Так будет дублироваться только вызов этой функции (всего одна строчка)

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Ваш вопрос слишком обобщенный, целые книги и курсы лекций представляют для решения данной проблемы. Существуют подходы для решения проблемы: ООП, функциональное программирование, использование шаблонов проектирования. Решение для Вашего примера будет зависеть от количества и типов входных данных, реализации методов sort и saveToFile. В простейшем случае, для работы со стандартными типами данных (String, Integer ...), можно использовать полиморфизм (методы sort, saveToFile будут перегружены с аргументами соответствующего типа), либо лямбды (передавать в метод кусок кода, который будет определять реализацию сортировки или преобразование перед записью в файл). Можно так же посмотреть ответ на вопрос  [Обобщённый метод для чтения данных из файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711316)

Comment: Это я тот вопрос и задал :-). Про полиморфизм не совсем понял. Вы имеет ввиду перегрузку (overload) или переопределение (override) методов?

Comment: перегрузка методов, что бы принимали разные аргументы, например sort(List<String>), sort(List<Integer>);